How to implement state managed by auth reducer in angular auth guard using new CanActivateFn instead of deprecated CanActivate?
// auth.guard.ts
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private store: Store<fromAuth.AuthState>, private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.store.pipe(
      select(fromAuth.selectUser), // Select user from the auth state
      map((user) => {
        if (user) {
          return true; // User is logged in, allow access to the route
        } else {
          this.router.navigate(['/login']); // User is not logged in, navigate to login page
          return false;
        }
      })
    );
  }
}


I am using ngrx to manage auth state and use it in auth guard. CanActivate is deprecated and I want to use CanActivateFn to guard route wrt to auth state from auth reducer, fromAuth.

To adapt your existing AuthGuard logic to use CanActivateFn, you need to follow these steps:

Update your import statements to include CanActivateFn.
Create the CanActivateFn function using the provided store and router.

Here is how you can refactor your AuthGuard class to use CanActivateFn:

Update the import statements:

Ensure you have the necessary imports for the new functional guard implementation.
import { inject } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivateFn } from '@angular/router';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { fromAuth } from '../path-to-auth-state'; // Adjust the path to your auth state

2.Create the authGuard function using CanActivateFn:
export const authGuard: CanActivateFn = () => {
  const store = inject(Store<fromAuth.AuthState>);
  const router = inject(Router);

  return store.pipe(
    select(fromAuth.selectUser), // Adjust the selector to match your state
    map((user) => {
      if (user) {
        return true; // User is logged in, allow access to the route
      } else {
        router.navigate(['/login']); // User is not logged in, navigate to login page
        return false;
      }
    })
  );
};


Use the authGuard in your route configuration:

In your routing module, replace the old canActivate guard with the new authGuard function.
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { authGuard } from './path-to-auth-guard'; // Adjust the path to your auth guard

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'protected-route',
    component: ProtectedComponent,
    canActivate: [authGuard]
  },
  // Other routes
];


Ensure your auth state and selector are correctly set up:

Make sure that your fromAuth.selectUser selector and AuthState are correctly defined in your NgRx setup.
// auth.selectors.ts
import { createSelector } from '@ngrx/store';
import { AuthState } from './auth.reducer'; // Adjust the path to your auth reducer

export const selectAuthState = (state: AppState) => state.auth;

export const selectUser = createSelector(
  selectAuthState,
  (state: AuthState) => state.user
);


Delay in update of auth state in reducer is stopping authentication in guard to return true, even after correct login.   Manually triggering change detection in login component, after login dispatch did not help. any help would be great.
